# How to properly reference counter

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, tcolorbox

I have a set of different tcolorboxes defined that I use to  indicate when something is important, when something is just a comment, etc. And I have created a counter `\newcounter{BoxCounter}` that is global to all this boxes so they are all numerated no matter which type of box they are, in the way Box 1, Box 2, Box 3, ...

The problem is that I don't know how exactly to make a `\ref` to one of this boxes. I have defined things like this:

```
\newcounter{BoxCounter}

\newtcolorbox{Comentario}[2][] {
colback=ComentarioBoxBackgroundColor,
colframe=ComentarioBoxFrameColor,
center, 
valign=top, 
halign=left,
breakable,
enhanced,
title=\bfseries\sffamily #2 \hfill Box \refstepcounter{BoxCounter}\theBoxCounter,
#1
}

\newtcolorbox{Importante}[2][] {
colback=EcuacionImportanteBoxBackgroundColor,
colframe=EcuacionImportanteBoxFrameColor,
center, 
valign=top, 
halign=left,
before skip=1cm, % Espacio en blanco antes del recuadro.
after skip=1cm, % Espacio en blanco después del recuadro.
breakable,
enhanced,
title=\bfseries\sffamily #2 \hfill Box \refstepcounter{BoxCounter}\theBoxCounter,
#1
}
```

where the first argument (optional) is of the form `label = some box` so then I use `\ref{some box`. The problem is that while the numbering of the box is just 1, 2, 3, ... the reference prints in the format 1.1 and so on.

How could I make this references print in the same format they are printed in the box titles?

Comment: You're using a wrong approach here. The label is using something completely different as base, not the `\refstepcounter` information

Comment: Related (but no duplicate: ) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408186/tcolorbox-how-to-reference-boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `label=...` option of `tcolorbox` is only useful if the stepping of the counter is done by the `tcolorbox` mechanism, so use `use counter=BoxCounter` and not `\refstepcounter`, otherwise `label=` would grab the last `\@currentlabel`, which might be left over from a previous call of  `\section` etc.

See also [tcolorbox: how to reference boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408186/tcolorbox-how-to-reference-boxes)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}




\newcounter{BoxCounter}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=BoxCounter]{Comentario}[2][] {
%colback=ComentarioBoxBackgroundColor,
%colframe=ComentarioBoxFrameColor,
center, 
valign=top, 
halign=left,
breakable,
enhanced,
title=\bfseries\sffamily #2 \hfill Box \theBoxCounter,
#1
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter={BoxCounter}]{Importante}[2][] {
%colback=EcuacionImportanteBoxBackgroundColor,
%colframe=EcuacionImportanteBoxFrameColor,
center, 
valign=top, 
halign=left,
before skip=1cm, % Espacio en blanco antes del recuadro.
after skip=1cm, % Espacio en blanco después del recuadro.
breakable,
enhanced,
title=\bfseries\sffamily #2 \hfill Box \theBoxCounter,
#1
}

\begin{document}


See \ref{foo} and \ref{foobar}

\begin{Comentario}[label=foo]{}

\end{Comentario}

\begin{Importante}[label={foobar}]{}

\end{Importante}

\end{document}
```

[image]